# Is there a lambda function in Scala?

Tags: function, scala, lambda, closures

I have a Java class that has access to a transaction context that I'd like to use from Scala. So I thought that I'd write a Java method that takes a Scala function and calls it inside the transaction -

```
class Context {
    @Transactional public void runInTx(Function0<scala.Unit> f) {
        f.apply();
    }
```

So far so good. I'd like to be able to pass a Scala closure to it

```
def deleteItems(ids: Set[Long]) = {
  context.runInTx { ids foreach { dao.delete(_) } }
}
```

but can't because `runInTx` isn't actually call by name, and `ids foreach { dao.delete(_) }` isn't actually a `Function0`.

Now I can solve this problem with a small thunk

```
def deleteItems(ids: Set[Long]) = {
  def localApply(f: => Unit) = context.applyInTx(f _)
  localApply { ids foreach { dao.delete(_) } }
}
```

but it seems to me that I need a lambda function to produce an unnamed `Function0` out of a code block.

Does such a thing exist in the API, or how would I go about writing it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can tell the compiler to interpret the block as a function rather than a statement to be called immediately by adding the (in this case lack of) parameters.

So in this case:

```
def deleteItems(ids: Set[Long]) = {
  context.runInTx {() => ids foreach { dao.delete(_) } }
}
```

`() => ids foreach { dao.delete(_) }` is the full form of the function literal. The compiler allows the parameter list to be omitted in places where it can infer that a function is required - this is true for call by name, but doesn't seem to be true when passing to a method taking a `Function`